# Fiware Orion CB Get entities of a type

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have inserted over a thousand entities of a specific type in my orion but when I try to get them it only returns to me 19 of them. Is there anything I can do so I can retrieve all the entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found it.

```
GET <orion_host>:1026/v2/entities?limit=1000
```

max limit is 1000